# Spark coalesce on rdd resulting in less partitions than expected

Tags: apache-spark-sql, partitioning, coalesce

We are running a spark batch job which performs following operations :

1. Create dataframe by reading from hive table
2. Convert dataframe to rdd
3. Store the rdd into list

Above steps are performed for 2 different tables and a variable ( called minNumberPartitions ) is set which holds the minimum number of partitions out of the 2 RDDs created.

When the job starts coalesce value is initialized to a constant value. This value is used to coalesce the above created RDDs only if it is less than the minNumberPartitions ( set in above step ). But, if coalesce value is greater than minNumberPartitions then it is re-set to minNumberPartitions ( i.e coalesceValue = minNumberPartitions ) and then coalesce happens to both the RDDs created with this value.

In our scenario, we are facing issue in the later condition when coalesce value is greater than minNumberPartitions. So the scenario is somewhat like this :

CoalesceValue is initialized to 20000, Number of partition of RDD1 created from Dataframe1 after reading from hivetable1 is 187, Number of partition of RDD2 created from Dataframe2 after reading from hivetable2 is 10. So the minNumberPartitions is set to 10.

Hence coalesceValue is getting reset to 10 and coalesce of respective RDDs happen with the value 10 i.e RDD1.coalesce(10, false, null) and RDD2.coalesce(10, false, null) [ Here shuffle in coalesce is set to false and ordering is set to null ].

According to common understanding, number of partitions of RDD1 should be reduced from 187 to 10 and RDD2 should remain the same i.e 10. In this case, number of partitions for RDD1 is getting reduced to 10 from 187, but for RDD2 number of partitions is getting reduced from 10 to 9. Due to this behaviour some operations are getting hampered and final spark job is getting failed.

Please help us understand if coalesce works differently on the RDD when coalesce value is same as that of number of partitions of the RDD.

UPDATE :
I found a Open Jira Ticket ( [SPARK-13365](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-13365) ) for the same issue but it is not conclusive. Moreover i don't understand the meaning of the statement in the above mentioned Jira ticket

> ' One case I've seen this is actually when users do coalesce(1000)
>   without the shuffle which really turns into a coalesce(100) '